# Object has texture but no uv map

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I downloaded a 3d model (Crash Bandicoot) and it has the textures and they render fine, but there is no uv map. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I can see the seams and they mostly fit the parts, but as you, I cannot see the UV's. But some of the seams however does not make sense. The belt is a complete circle of faces, no seams. Perhaps this is mapped to the face attributes in some way?

Comment: I don't know. I tried duplicating it, then I unwrapped the object, thus giving it a uv map, and then transferring the textures with the bake option. But it didn't work because both objects need to have a uv map I guess.

Comment: @martin the UV map is there, you just need to zoom out, because the islands are far away from the center of the coordinates.

Comment: @Denis THANK YOU! it all makes sense now, and the belt is a complete circle because the UVs are overlapping!